# How to check the username of postgreSQL on windows 10

Tags: postgresql

I know my password but I don't remember my username. I tried "postgres" but it didn't work. How can I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shut down the database and start it in single user mode:

```sh
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\postgres.exe" --single -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data" postgres
```

Then query the users:

```
SELECT usename FROM pg_authid WHERE rolcanlogin;
```